# getting value of inputs created by ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs, radio-button, angularjs-ng-repeat

I created a radiobutton input but struggling to get the values of selected inputs.

this is the radiobuttons input I created

```
<ul ng-repeat="item in riskModel">
    <li>
      <input type="radio" name="rdbRisk" ng-value="{{item.value}}" />
      {{item.text}}
    </li>
</ul>
```

and this the ng-model definiton in controller

```
$scope.riskModel = [
        { id: 0, text: "A", value: "" },
        { id: 1, text: "B Risk", value: "YR" },
        { id: 2, text: "C Risk", value: "OR" },
        {id:3,text:"D Risk",value:"DR"}
    ]
```

I want to take the selected value and send it to a function as a parameter but so far I failed to get any results.

Comment: `ng-value="{{item.value}}"` should be `ng-value="item.value"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Declare your `ng-model` variable as object `$scope.radioModel = {};`

```js
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);

myApp.controller('GreetingController', ['$scope', function($scope) {
  //$scope.radioModel = {};
  $scope.riskModel = [
        { id: 0, text: "A", value: "" },
        { id: 1, text: "B Risk", value: "YR" },
        { id: 2, text: "C Risk", value: "OR" },
        {id:3,text:"D Risk",value:"DR"}
    ]
  $scope.changeValue = function(value){
    console.log(value.selected);
  }
  
}]);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<body ng-app="myApp">
  <div ng-controller="GreetingController" ng-init="radioModel={}">
    Get selected value : {{radioModel.selected}}
  <ul ng-repeat="item in riskModel">
    <li>
      <input type="radio" ng-model="radioModel.selected" name="rdbRisk" ng-value="item.value" ng-change="changeValue(radioModel)"/>
      {{item.text}}
    </li>
</ul>
</div>
</body>
```

Comment: I'm writing the values to console and they work nice at first. But when I click on a radiobutton second time, value doesnt get written on console.

Comment: @EgeBayrak Try my example

Comment: @EgeBayrak I think you should use ngChange to get selected value in your controller, See my answer I've console also to get the value of selected radio. Let me know if you still face any issue.

Comment: @EgeBayrak : Happy to see that, finally it works for you :)

Comment: one tiny thing though, somehow the input I choose doesn't have the black dot inside the circle so there is no way of seeing which option is chosen. I never encountered such a thing in radiobuttons before actually

Comment: @EgeBayrak I don't think there is any problem you get by using this code, you can check my example, it's working and showing selected option as well.. May be you're getting problem by your css. just check your class / style.

Answer (score 1):

Dont use expression `{{}}` in an input ,

```
<input type="radio" name="rdbRisk" ng-value="item.value" />
```

[**DEMO**](https://plnkr.co/edit/ZDu036Hq0kjh0RFk6jKG?p=preview)

best option is to use ng-model and get the selected value,

```
  <input type="radio" ng-model="selected" name="rdbRisk"     ng-click="display(selected)" />
```

[**DEMO**](https://plnkr.co/edit/5icTcKsIKbo1U88duHy3?p=preview)

Comment: ok but I still dont know how to take the input value. Shall I use something like ng-change? Not sure if it would work inside a ng-repeat tbh.

Comment: @EgeBayrak Use ng-click

Answer (score 1):

You forgot `ng-model`

`<input type="radio" ng-model="selectedValue" name="rdbRisk" ng-value="item.value" />`

Access in controller with `$scope.selectedValue`

Answer (score 1):

Fiddle that shows [your working example](http://jsfiddle.net/ncapito/rbqu9jdn/):

On your `input`, add a `ng-model` which will be where you want to save your selection, and  remove the surrounding `{{}}` on `{{item.value}}`.

```
<li>
  <input type="radio" 
        ng-model="mySelection.selected" 
        name="rdbRisk"
        ng-value="item.value" />
  {{item.text}}
</li>
```